# how to get child positions of dynamically added edittext in linearlayout?

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

**Here,I have used list with repeated string.I am going to run loop by saying if the item is "1" then edittext input type should be number if its "4" normal edittext.Now my question is how to get id in onclick event of edittext.The below code is working until onclick.**

```
        list.add("1");
        list.add("1");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("4");
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            String str=list.get(i);
            editText1=new EditText(Second.this);
            editText1.setId(i);
            if(str.equals("1")){


                editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                linearLayout.addView(editText1);



            }
            else if(str.equals("4")){
                linearLayout.addView(editText1);
                }
          linearLayout.addView(txt);
        }


        int position=linearLayout .getChildCount();
        Log.d("linearLayout","count"+position);
    editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int currentViewId =view.getId();
        Log.d("linearLayout","currentViewId"+currentViewId);
    }
});
```

*Please help me to solve this in simple way*

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `if(i == 2) ...`. You don't need their IDs if you're going by position in the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: you haven't given any id to your view when adding them to linear layout

Comment: how can you expect anything in `v.getId()` if you didn't set the IDs?

Comment: MikeM is right: you dont need any view ID

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Yep my fault I forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way setId for view controls.

```
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin);
    textView.setText(s);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        txt=new TextView(Second.this);
        txt.setText(""+i+"");
        txt.setId(i);
        linearLayout.addView(txt);
    }
    int position=linearLayout .getChildCount();
    Log.d("linearLayout","count"+position);

    for(int i = 0; i < linearLayout .getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        int currentViewId =v.getId();
        Log.d("linearLayout","currentViewId"+currentViewId);
        if(currentViewId == 1) {
            txt.setTextColor(Second.this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

        }
        else if (currentViewId==2){

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to save my time .please note my  edited question

Comment: pass view object when click perform into interface method.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        txt=new TextView(Second.this);
        txt.setText(""+i+"");
        txt.setId(""+i+"");
        linearLayout.addView(txt);
    }
```